# Json Differences between angularjs and play framework

Tags: json, angularjs, scala, playframework

When i post from angularjs

```
{name:"John", age: 26}
```

i get BadRequest, however if is manually post

```
{"name":"John", "age": 26}
```

it works

in the Scala/Play side its the simple case class with Json formatting

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class Customer(name: String, age: Int)

implicit val customerFormat = Json.format[Customer]
```

the Action is a simple one

```
def save = Action(parse.json) { request =>
  request.body.validate[Customer].map { customer =>
      myDAO.saveCustomer(customer)
      Ok(toJson(customer))
    }.getOrElse(BadRequest("invalid json"))
  })
}
```

i guess the answer is either make angularjs quote the keys, or make play to ignore the the lack of keys, i'll need help on how do i do either of it, or am i missing something

Comment: How do you build and send the JSON-like data from AngularJS? Do you build it manually or use a library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In valid JSON, object keys must always be quoted. Try typing the object literal without the quotes into a [JSON validator](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) for confirmation.

It's important to note that [there are differences](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) between plain old Javascript object literals (POJOs) and JSON, with the JSON format being stricter. JSON is a string data type that happens to be valid Javascript. Technically, you obtain JSON data from Javascript code by `stringify`ing a POJO:

```
JSON.stringify({name:"John", age: 26})
// "{"name":"John","age":26}"
```